# Sorting applications by their trimmed name

Tags: applications

Is there anyway to for the app list to be sorted by applications' trimmed names?

E.g. in the screenshot below, the application " Flashlight" appears first because it contains the space at the beginning. I would like to avoid that.

[image]

I use a Samsung GALAXY S3 with a rooted Android 4.1.2.

Comment: To be honest, I just wouldn't install apps that use stupid tricks like this.

Comment: @DanHulme too true +1

Comment: @FranckDernincourt you can also rename the app.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN How can I rename an installed app?

Comment: @Franck - you can rename your file with a renaming app or you can use a file explorer/browser such as Total Commander (open source ), Astro File Manager, or any other. Always backup the original file first, then rename. IMHO - I would find another flashlight/torch app, preferably with minimal permission and already named right.

Comment: @Franck - also I forgot to add that Xposed framework has a couple of renaming modules as well. Some are in their own modules, while some are within other modules.